# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.forEach')

Tags: javascript, android, expo

I seem to have a problem with this app when using expos. The app initially starts fine then crashes with the below error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.forEach')


see actual code below:
_calcCardPositions (props = this.props) {
        const { items, sliderWidth, itemWidth } = props;

        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            this._positions[index] = {
                start: index * itemWidth
            };
            this._positions[index].end = this._positions[index].start + itemWidth;
        });
    }

    _initInterpolators () {
        const { items, firstItem } = this.props;
        let interpolators = [];

        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            interpolators.push(new Animated.Value(index === firstItem ? 1 : 0));
        });
        this.setState({ interpolators });
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add actual code

Comment: _calcCardPositions (props = this.props) {
        const { items, sliderWidth, itemWidth } = props;

        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            this._positions[index] = {
                start: index * itemWidth
            };
            this._positions[index].end = this._positions[index].start + itemWidth;
        });
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `(items|| []).forEach` when items is **null** or **undefined**

Comment: `items?.forEach` should be even better